# What is a CSS pixel in mobile devices?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have been programming the backend mostly and started learning CSS two weeks back .All these days I was working with laptops and have now started learning responsive design and how things behave in  mobile devices . I have been really struggling to understand few concepts for devices with higher pixel density especially how big pixels end up displaying in mobile devices . I've read a lot and ended up being more confused than before .

I understand there are two types of pixels : a) Device Pixels - The actual pixels
in a device ( eg my laptop has 1366 x 768 ) and b) CSS pixels - The pixels that we use in CSS (eg width :200px) . There is also a device to pixel ratio which signifies how many device pixel equals to how many CSS pixels . On my laptop this ratio is 1 ,  so each pixel I use in the CSS maps to each device pixels .On my laptop if I create a box with width : 660px this will be rougly half of my viewport width : (1366-45)/2 =660px , the 45px for the scrollbar etc .

However I do not understand what happens when we use pixel values for mobile devices . Consider the case of Apple iphone 6 which has 750 device pixel and 375 CSS pixel with a pixel ratio of 2 . Now If I draw a box with width : 375px , it shows up as 150 ( do not know what px this is ) in my Chrome Mobile emulator like shown below :

[image]

My questions are :

1. Is'nt the ruler in the mobile emulator in CSS pixels ? ( Since the width of the ruler shows up as 375 px ) .
2. If the ruler is in CSS pixel then why does my box ( whose width is 375 CSS px)
   shows up being 150 px on the ruler ? What is the relation between the ruler in the mobile emulator and the px that I use in my CSS ?
3. What exactly is the use of device pixel then ? Cant I see it ?

What I am trying to understand is how do I know how big my pixels will display in relation to the CSS width / physical width of the device in question .

Comment: _“Now If I draw a box with width : 375px , it shows up as 150”_ - sounds like your test document might not have a proper `viewport` meta tag set to begin with?

Comment: I tried with the viewport <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> and without it ...the result is the same

Comment: Then please start by showing us a [mre] of what you are doing, not just frontend screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to  might help to reset the browser zoom level or page width

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=0.5">
```